# Python Image Library installation

Tags: python

I just installed the 1.15 Python Image Library in the following folder:

```
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\
```

However, when I write

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw
```

I get a error saying unresolved import. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I ran a .exe file from this site http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ and I'm using eclipse Juno if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual modules are just `Image`, `ImageOps`, `ImageDraw`; the `PIL` package is something one particular distro decided to tack on because they thought those module names were too generic, but they're not actually found in PIL.

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean, but how do I fix it?

Comment: Stop trying to import them from `PIL`; just import them directly.